# Dell inspiron 3542 cd rom is not showing (in windows explorer)

Tags: windows-8.1, dell-inspiron, cd-drive

I bought a laptop "Dell Inspiron 3542 with Windows 8.1 Pro"
But when I open "Windows Explorer", I can't see my DVD/CD rom drive.. Can someone please Help me. I've check many tutorials on YouTube and google my problem but I cannot fix it, So I thought, I should ask this Question Here.
Thanks a lot:)

Comment: By default drives with no media are hidden, Folder Options>View Tab>hide empty drives in the Computer folder, uncheck the box.

Answer (score 0):

By default drives with no media inserted are hidden, Folder Options>View Tab>hide empty drives in the Computer folder, uncheck the box and hit Ok button.

[image]

If the drive still does not appear with media inserted see this artcle

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314060